# Copy-pasting text into my text area returns a blank result?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that submits to a database and those submissions are then echoed onto a page. When I type text into the textarea, all is good. But, if I copy paste into the text area, the text is entered into the database just fine, but it echoes blank.

This is my form:

```
        <form method="post" action="post.php" id="messageForm" autocomplete="off">
            <table border="0" align="center">
                <tr><td id="formBlock" style><span>Name</span></td>
                <td><input id="messageName" name="name" type="text" value="Anonymous" maxlength="32" required>
                    <input style="margin-right: -1px; margin-left: -4px;" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Message"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="formBlock"><span>Title</span></td>
                    <td><input id="messageTitle" name="title" type="text" maxlength="32" width="20"></td></tr><br>
                <tr><td id="formBlock"><span>Message</span></td>
                    <td><textarea onkeyup="countChar(this)" name="message" rows="6" cols="50" form="messageForm" maxlength="2000" style="font-family: arial;" required></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr> <td id="formBlock"><span>Tags</span></td>
                    <td><input id="messageTags" name="tags" type="text" maxlength="64" width="100" placeholder="separated by commas: cats, anime, zelda, etc"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And here's how it is echoed:

```
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<br><div id='messageBar'><b><a class='rateup' href='javascript:;' data-id=' " . $row['id'] . " ' title='vote up'>&#9650;</a> ";
                    echo $row["rating"];
                    echo " <a class='ratedown' href='index.php' title='vote down'>&#9660;</a> </b>";
                    echo "Posted by <b>";
                    echo htmlspecialchars($row["name"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    echo "</b> on ";
                    echo $row["date"];
                    echo " at ";
                    echo $row["time"];
                    if (!empty($row['title'])) {
                        echo " - <b>";
                        echo htmlspecialchars($row["title"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        echo "</b>";
                    }
                    echo "<span style='float: right'>#";
                    echo $row["id"];
                    echo "</span>";
                    echo "</div><div id='messageContent'>";
                    echo htmlspecialchars($row["message"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    echo "<br><br><span id='commentLink'><a class='noStyle' href=''>reply to this post&nbsp;</a></span>";
                    echo "<br></div><br><hr>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<center><i>it's dusty in here</i></center>";
                echo "<br>";
            }
```

I really have no idea why this is happening, and I've never seen anything like it before.

EDIT:

New development, I removed htmlspecialchars and it works fine, but I can't have it disabled because then people can put code into the messages. What's the workaround?

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Nope. It goes through the form just fine so nothing is triggered.

Comment: When you say `it echoes blank` do you mean the page is blank or the individual fields (`$row["name"]`) are?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific. All fields are fine except for the ['message'] field. It's there in the database row, but it's not being echoed.

Comment: Try to `var_dump` it and see what you get.

Comment: I've never used that before, how do I use it?

Comment: `var_dump($row["message"]);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: var_dump shows the message as it is in the database.

Comment: New development, I removed htmlspecialchars and it works fine, but I can't have it disabled because then people can put code into the messages. What's the workaround?

Comment: `var_dump` the the return from the `speical_chars` call. What specifically is breaking?

Comment: I did `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($row["message"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));` and it returned `string(0) "" `

Comment: Okay, so something is wrong with that value. See the manual's return section for that function. `If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.`

Comment: It doesn't make any sense though. If I typed out the message it comes out fine, but if I copy text and paste it into the textarea it doesn't work. That makes no sense.

Comment: Can't really help you because I don''t know what we are working with (data/characters wise).

Comment: Is there anything you would need to know specifically? I really need to figure this out.

Comment: Did you try adding either of the constants to the function to resolve the issue to the function?

Comment: I fixed it. Tried changing ENT_QUOTES to ENT_SUBSTITUTE but that made nothing work, so I just removed the ENT_ and the UTF-8 all together, just using htmlspecialchars(whatever) and it works now.

Comment: You don't drop the `ENT_QUOTES`, it should work with that, `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE`, maybe the encoding of that column/string isn't UTF8. That's kind of a temporary solution if you wanted to use that value in an element it would be insecure.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it works but it is a temporary solution... I tried sending HTML, PHP, and Javascript through the form and it all came through as just plain text, which is what I wanted. Is there any other problem with it after that?